# Build fails for React Native in iOS due to RNSVG

Tags: react-native

I have a react native app which is working fine on android but when i try to run `npx react-native run-ios` I'm getting the following error

```
2023-02-15 17:23:36.048 xcodebuild[81512:522416] [MT] IDEFileReferenceDebug: [Load] <IDESwiftPackageCore.IDESwiftPackageSpecialFolderFileReference, 0x7fd3caff3490: name:Docs.docc path:group:Docs.docc> Failed to load container at path: /Users/shubhagarwal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weedlemobiledapptraining-cngaloxjuncutwengkgnppfnmbtd/SourcePackages/checkouts/swift-protobuf/Sources/protoc-gen-swift/Docs.docc, Error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDEContainerErrorDomain Code=6 "Cannot open "Docs.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder"." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot open "Docs.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder".}
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/shubhagarwal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weedlemobiledapptraining-cngaloxjuncutwengkgnppfnmbtd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSVG/RNSVG.framework/RNSVG normal (in target 'RNSVG' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

This is how my Podfile looks like

```
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/package.json')"`), "native_modules")
require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '12.0'
install! 'cocoapods',
:deterministic_uuids => false


target 'weedlemobiledapptraining' do
  use_expo_modules!
  use_modular_headers!
  # use_frameworks!

  config = use_native_modules!
  # use_frameworks! :linkage => podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks'].to_sym if podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks']

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled] || podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes',
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Dir.pwd}/.."
  )

  # Uncomment to opt-in to using Flipper
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work
  #
  # if !ENV['CI']
  #   use_flipper!()
  # end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end

  post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
  end

end
```

Versions :

node : 14.21.2
React : 17.0.2
React Native : 0.68.2
XCode : 12.1

I've tried everything that I could find on the internet.

- Reinstalled Node Modules and Pods several times
- Tried to make the build without use_frameworks! or use_modular_headers!
- Adding glog to the podfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run

```
pod install --project-directory=ios --repo-update
```

command to install pod dependencies

Comment: this resolved the error that I was getting, finally i'm getting a new error after 2 days of head banging. Thanks!

Comment: @shubhraagarwal can you mark question as answered